# power shell to move files from a directory that are over 7 years old

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use power shell to move files from a directory that are over 7 years old. IF i don't have permission i want to log that folder then move to the next one. I want to exclude a folder that i know i don't have access to. the code is below . It doesn't work because it doesn't actually exclude the folder i want excluded, and if it comes across a permisssion i want to log that issue, then move to the next folder. it fails when it comes across the first permission issue.

```
# Set the source and destination directories
    $sourceDir = "T:\New T Drive"
    $destDir = "T:\New T Drive\Archive"
    # Set the date threshold (7 years ago)
    $dateThreshold = (Get-Date).AddYears(-7)
    # Set the excluded folder
    $excludedFolder = "T:\New T Drive\Executive Director\"
    # Set the log file path
    $logFile = "C:\logs\file-migration.log"

    # Get all files in the source directory and its subdirectories that haven't been accessed in 
    the last 7 years, excluding the excluded folder

    Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -Recurse -Exclude $excludedFolder |

    Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastAccessTime -lt $dateThreshold } |

    ForEach-Object {

         # Construct the destination path

        $destPath = $_.FullName.Replace($sourceDir, $destDir)
        # Create the destination directory if it doesn't exist
        $null = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path (Split-Path -Path $destPath -Parent) -Force
        # Try to copy the file
        try {
            Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $destPath -Recurse -Force
           # Write the copied file to the screen
            Write-Host "Copied $($_.FullName) to $destPath"
        }

        catch {
            # Log any permission errors to the log file
            Write-Output "Permission denied for $($_.FullName). Error: $_" | Out-File $logFile -Append
        }

    }
```

Comment: Best way to do this is with a `Stack<T>`. Even if `-Exclude` from `Get-ChildItem` would work it would only exclude that folder (not its childs). As aside, your destination directory is inside the source, should it be excluded too?

Comment: As aside, `-Exclude` only works on the **Name** of the folder or file. Not on the full path

Comment: what is the syntax for using stack<t> ? i've never used it before, and i'm not an expert on powershell. also, i need to move the files, not copy, i think that's part of my issue.

Comment: also, can i exclude more than one folder in the exclude variable ?

Comment: _"it fails when it comes across the first permission issue"_.. You don't know the actual reason because you always assume that permission denied is always the error that forced the code to enter the catch block. For debugging, add a `Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"` in the catch to see what really happened. BTW, inside a `catch{}`, the `$_` automatic variable contains the error object, no longer a reference to the file, so `$_.FullName` won't work there anymore